# Python module importing functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my head around Python modules. I currently have the current setup. My main code in file test.py:

```
from superpackage import supermodule
supermodule.woww()
```

I then have a directory named `superpackage` inside this folder is the module file `supermodule.py` defined as so:

```
def woww():
    print "wow"
```

In the same directory I have a blank `__init__.py`.

The code executes. Is there a way to import the contents of the package so I can just call `woww()` without the `supermodule.`? When working with just modules I can do `from supermodule import woww`, but is there an equivalent for packages?

Comment: `from superpackage.supermodule import woww`

Comment: @CoryKramer This should be an answer